# Change textColorSecondary for PreferenceThemeOverlay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have white `textColorSecondary` in `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppTheme.PreferenceTheme</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And black `textColorSecondary` in `PreferenceTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme.PreferenceTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

But preference summary (which should have the colour of `textColorSecondary`) is still white.

[image]

How can I make it black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do was to create a new theme for `SettingsActivity` and set it in `AndroidManifest`

So, in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    ...
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
        ..
        android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme"
        />
```